# Getting Segmentation Fault error while replacing unicode to a whitespace in string of C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, replace

I am trying to replace **Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00C2)** i.e **Â** to a whitespace " " in a string `str`, while running through some cases it is giving me **segmentation fault**. Can any one suggest me how it is invalid memory access.
Is I am doing it right way?
Is there any other way to do it?

```
string str = "transaction applies: Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â {79}";
void cleanup(string& str)
    {   
        string unicode = "\u00C2";
        size_t pos = str.find(unicode);
        while(str.find(unicode, pos)!=string::npos && pos != str.length())
        {   
            pos = str.find(unicode, pos);
            str.replace(pos, unicode.length(), " " ); //unicode replace by a space  
            // this above line is giving segmentation fault
            pos = pos + unicode.length();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Output:

Comment: You're overthinking this. `for (char &c:str) {if (c == (char)0xA0) c=' ';}`

Comment: Equating a NBSP with Â is confusing. I'd recommend being more precise about what your strings actually are. Both of these might have the same byte sequence in different encodings, but they're very different things. It's kind of like taking an integer, reinterpreting the bits as a double, then equating the resulting double value with the integer value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your input, but it is not changing string str i.e not replacing Â to ' ' (space).

Comment: @chris can you tell me which line you think, I am equating a NBSP with Â , and I want to  replace only Â to space if it exists.

Comment: Â is U+00C2 while nbsp is U+00A0. These are two different code points.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Unicode code point `A0` is encoded as `C2 A0` in UTF-8. Simply replacing the `A0` bytes is not enough. The problem here can be solved by tracing through with a debugger or a bunch of `printf`s.

Comment: U+00A0  is actually `á`

Comment: @Mohit: no! U+00A0 is indeed NO-BREAK space. Byte `'\xa0'` is the representation of `'à'` (U+00E1) in charset cp850.

Comment: @HarshGiri, "Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00C2) i.e Â"

Comment: It's incidental to the error you're setting, but you also seem to be doing `str.find` *twice* in every loop. Once inside the loop condition then again inside the loop. This is going to be terrible for performance if your strings are large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing this is enough.

```
std::string str("transaction applies: Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â {79}");
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char c) -> char {return (c == (char)'\u00C2') ? ' ': c ; });
```

Comment: I am getting this error `error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
   std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char c) -> char {return (c == (char)'\u00C2') ? ' ': c ; });`

Comment: For replacing a single `char` value, you can use `std:replace()` instead of `std::transform()`, eg: `std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\xC2', ' ');`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are replacing all of the characters with spaces, followed by searching for a next special character. After you attempt to replace a non-existant character -- `pos = string::npos`.

Here is a simple modification of your while loop so that it works (helpful `cout` for tracing included):

```
void cleanup(string& str) {
  string unicode = "\u00C2"; // \u00C2 is Â
  size_t pos = str.find(unicode);
  while(pos != string::npos) {
    cout << "str: " << str << "\tpos: " << pos << endl;
    str.replace(pos, unicode.length(), " ");
    pos = pos + unicode.length();
    pos = str.find(unicode, pos);
  }
}
```

You can (and probably should) modify this to be a for-each loop over the characters of your string, or a do-while loop to simplify the code. But the reason it does not work is as stated above, you tried replaced on a `pos` that didn't exist.

Not suggesting this is the best program, but a possible conversion to for-each loop, so you can see an example in C++11:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Using u16string because of unicode characters
void cleanup(u16string& str) {
  for(auto& c : str)
    if(c == u'\u00C2')
      c = u' ';
}

int main() {
  u16string str = u"transaction applies: \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 \u00C2 {79}";
  cleanup(str);

  wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
  cout << convert.to_bytes(str) << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is likely the encoding of the string. See my example with u16string to see a possible encoding. Basically, in your editor don't use the literal Â. Use \u00C2 in the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion between an unicode character and its utf-8 representation. NO-BREAK SPACE is indeed unicode character U+00A0 and its utf-8 representation is `"\xc2\xa0"`. And `Â` is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX, or unicode character U+00C2, and its unicode representation is `"\xc3\x82"`.

That means that your initial string does not contain any NO-BREAK SPACE. If your editor charset is Latin1 or windows cp1252, it will contains repetitions of "\xc2\x20" (ie latin1 encoded 'Â' and space), and if it is utf8, it will contains repetitions of "\xc3\x82\x20" (ie utf8 encoded 'Â' and space). When you then search for occurence of "\u00A0", you actually search for occurences of "\xc2\xa0" which is not present in original string. The segmentation fault is caused by `pos` being `std::string::npos`: `str.find(unicode, pos)` invokes undefined behaviour.

What to do: choose your side. As you are using narrow strings, you must decide what encoding you use. If you use utf8 (common in Linux world) then a NO-BREAK SPACE character is a string of 2 characters length: `{ 0xc2, 0xa0 }`. And this line:

```
string unicode = "\u00A0";
```

is exactly the same as this one:

```
string unicode = "\xc2\xa0";
```

and most of all control that you have a valid pos before using it:

```
   ...
   size_t pos = str.find(unicode);
   if (pos == string::npos) return;
   ...
```